# Why are colons escaped with a backslash when you generate a properties file using the Java API?

Tags: java, properties-file

Sample code:

```
public final class Test
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("foo", "bar:baz");

        // Yeah, this supposes a Unix-like system
        final Path path = Paths.get("/tmp/x.properties");

        try (
            // Requires Java 8!
            final Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path);
        ) {
            properties.store(writer, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I:

```
$ cat /tmp/x.properties 
# The date here
foo=bar\:baz
```

the colon is escaped with a backslash. In fact, all colons are.

The strange thing is that if I generate a properties file by hand and *do not* "escape" the colon, the properties are read just as well.

So, why does the writing process of `Properties` (this is the case whether you use a `Writer` or `OutputStream` by the way) escape colons this way?

Comment: For reference: it will also do the same for `=`, `:`, `#` and `!` ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Properties.java#628)).

Comment: [This line](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Properties.java#364) implies that there is a difference of behaviour if the colon is not escaped.

Comment: Because that's what is specified to occur in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `load` method of the [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class mention the following:

> **The key contains all of the characters in the line starting with the first non-white space character and up to, but not including, the first unescaped '=', ':'**, or white space character other than a line terminator. **All of these key termination characters may be included in the key by escaping them with a preceding backslash character**;
>
> ...
>
> As an example, each of the following three lines specifies the key "Truth" and the associated element value "Beauty":
>
> `Truth = Beauty`
>
> `Truth:Beauty`
>
> `Truth                    :Beauty`

So the colon can be used to determine the end of the key in a property file.

Answer (score 1):

Because the properties file syntax allows using colon as separator between keys and values instead of an equals character (you can use just a space), so to prevent issues if you change the separator escaping them can be a good idea.

For example:

```
# Add spaces to the key
key\ 2 = value for "key 2"
# colon :
key3: This is key 3
#space
key4 This is key 4
```

You can check other options in the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties)